# Military date/time to_char meridian indicator option

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, datetime-format

Running PostgreSQL 7.4(Yep we're upgrading)

Field is data type: `timestamp with time zone`

Format is like this: `2011-06-30 19:18:07-04`

Converting to this format:

```
to_char(datetime_field, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH12:MI:SS') AS "New Date"
```

Output is this:

```
06-30-2011 07:18:07
```

But I also need to add the meridian indicator.

Desired results:

```
// if AM
06-30-2011 07:18:07 AM

// if PM
06-30-2011 07:18:07 PM
```

Is there a option I can pass to get this?

So the example datetime I give

```
2011-06-30 19:18:07-04
```

should be this:

```
06-30-2011 07:18:07 PM
```

UPDATE:

Well I'm still looking for an option to pass but this is a workaround I did:

```
CASE WHEN date_part('HOUR', datetime_field) > 12
     THEN to_char(datetime_field, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')
     ELSE to_char(datetime_field, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
END AS "New Date"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation page (for v8.2)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE), you can use *any* pattern from this list: `AM`, `am`, `PM`, `pm`, `A.M.`, `a.m.`, `P.M.`, `p.m.`. The pattern chosen will define the style of the indicator in the output, but whether it will be *ante meridiem* or *post meridiem*, will entirely depend on the timestamp value.

So you don't need to employ CASE at all. Use whatever of the two:

- `to_char(datetime_field, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') AS "New Date"`
- `to_char(datetime_field, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM') AS "New Date"`

Was that what you were asking about?

Comment: I understand I can pass the AM/PM but is there an option so it adjusts itself? so if I pass 18:00:00 it would print out 06:00:00 PM?

Comment: @Phill Pafford: This is just what I mean: it will adjust automatically. If you pass `18:00` you'll get `06:00 PM`, and if you pass `06:00` you'll get `06:00 AM` **regardless of whether you use AM or PM in the formatting string**.

Comment: I do see you're referencing 8.2 and I'm currently running 7.4but I will test this out on Tuesday

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that it would adjust to the correct meridiem even if I just used one of the options

Answer (score 1):

to_char(datetime_field, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')

is working in last version, I'm not sure for 7.4

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-formatting.html

'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS' - 06-30-2011 07:18:07

DD-MM or MM-DD ?

Comment: yes to_char works in 7.4 and MM-DD is the format I wanted. I found a solution using the CASE statement in my update but I wanted to know if there is a flag or option I can set instead of having to add it manually?

Comment: AM, am, PM or pm meridiem indicator (without periods) 
A.M., a.m., P.M. or p.m. meridiem indicator (with periods)

Comment: I don't think you're getting the question. I'm not asking how to append the AM/PM, I'm asking is there an option to determine the meridian indicator? Like Mon displays the first 3 characters of the month or YYYY is the full year 2011. I want to know if there is an option like YYYY for the meridian indicator so I don't need to manually set it

Comment: @Phill Pafford: If I understand you correctly, you don't need to find out which indicator, AM or PM, to use in the formatting string. It will be determined automatically by the timestamp value. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Phill Pafford: `AM` or `A.M.` or `PM` or `P.M.` are **wilcards**, just like `YYYY`. Use whatever of these, effect is that same. It's working well for 7.4 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-formatting.html